# Как вызвать функцию, если она была передана аргументом JS

Tags: javascript

Есть одна функция, из которой нужно вызвать переданную в аргументах:

```
function testone(a) {}
testone(alert("123"));
```

В случае если вызывать ее таким методом:

```
function testone(a) {a();}
```

то, естественно, не срабатывают аргументы переданной функции, как быть?

Самая беда в том, что я точно помню, что когда-то давно сталкивался с такой проблемой и нашел решение, была какая-то стандартная функция, например, standart(a), которая выполняла переданную функцию с аргументами, только сейчас никак не могу вспомнить, как она называется.

Comment: Может, так:  

    function testone(a) {
        a.apply( this, [arg1, arg2] );
    }

Или так:  

    function testone(a) {
        a.call( this, arg1, arg2 );
    }

Comment: Нет, там была вся суть в том, что не надо было высчитывать аргументы, я же атрибутом a функции testone передаю уже готовую к вызову функцию с уже указанными аргументами, должен быть способ, наверное же, вызвать ее, не перечисляя аргументов. Вызвать ее таким образом, как показали вы, я могу и так:

    a(arg1,arg2,arg3,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере (`testone(alert("123"));`) вы передаёте не саму функцию, а результат её выполнения. Вызов функции происходит в момент передачи её в таком виде в качестве аргумента. Если бы вам не нужно было вызывать функцию с определёнными аргументами, то передача и последующий вызов выглядели бы так:

```
function testone(f) {
    f();
}

testone(alert);
```

Но если вам нужно передавать в вызываемую функцию аргументы, и вы не хотите передавать их отдельно от функции, то вам нужно спрятать их в замыкании:

```
function testone(f) {
     f();
}

testone(function() {
    alert("123");
});
```

Теперь вы передаёте в `testone` функцию, внутри которой спрятан вызов нужной вам функции с нужными вам аргументами.

Немного литературы:

- [Функции](http://javascript.ru/basic/functions)
- [Замыкания](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет метод `bind()` - http://learn.javascript.ru/bind